# xAxis hides after resize in react rechart

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-redux, recharts

I use react rechart library for creating a line chart. When I resize my browser window, the values or ticks in xAxis gets hidden. But I don't want the values in xAxis to get hidden. Kindly provide a solution to avoid the values in xAxis getting hidden.

My Line chart component code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, ResponsiveContainer, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ReferenceLine,
} from 'recharts';
import { lineChartXAxis, lineChartYAxis } from './chart.config';
// styles
import useStyles from "./styles";

const LineCharts = ({ dimensions, data, XAxisDataKey }) => {
    const {chartOuterWrap, chartInnerWrap} = useStyles()
    return ( 
        <div className={chartOuterWrap} style={dimensions}>
          <div className={chartInnerWrap}>
            <ResponsiveContainer>
              <LineChart height={'100%'} width={'100%'} data={data}>
                  <XAxis dataKey={XAxisDataKey}
                  tick={true}
                  interval={'preserveStartEnd'}
                  {...lineChartXAxis}
                  />
                  <YAxis
                  interval={0}
                  tick={true}
                  {...lineChartYAxis}
                   />
                  <Tooltip />
                  <Line type="monotone" strokeWidth={3} dataKey="uv" stroke="#24b32a" />
                  <Line type="monotone" strokeWidth={3} dataKey="pv" stroke="#fb8c00" />
                  <Line type="monotone" strokeWidth={3} dataKey="amt" stroke="#e53935" />
              </LineChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LineCharts;
```

I have also attached the image for easy understanding of the issue

[image]

After resizing the window

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1664) with Recharts, and the solution is to use customized tick marks:

```
const CustomizedAxisTick = props => {
  const { x, y, payload } = props

  return (
    <g transform={\`translate(${x},${y})\`}>
      <text dy={16} textAnchor='middle' fill='#666'>{payload.value}</text>
    </g>
  )
}
```

Then in the chart types AreaChart, BarChart, LineChart, ComposedChart or ScatterChart, include the `tick` prop in the [XAxis](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis)

```
<XAxis tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />} />
```

like this [CustomizedLabelLineChart example](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart).  Experiment with settings in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o6x11lvn7).

Answer (score -1):

Added `interval={0}` in the `<XAxis />`. It solved my issue.

Thanks to *yarv-dev* on Github.

Comment: You might want to add the link of GitHub resource here if you do have a link.